# How to group emails only by subject AND sender in Gmail

Tags: gmail

I need the group conversation feature, but I only want mails with same sender and same subject to be grouped. I have many senders who send me emails with the same title. These emails are all grouped in one conversation, so it's hard to identify and it's easy to miss some.

Can I do this? And if yes, how?

Comment: No, sorry. You can either have conversation view on or off. There's no way to tweak it.

Answer (score 1):

All you could do is switch the conversation view off and on. Switching it off would list all the emails in your inbox.